# How to read and process csv file using javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am struck in a problem where I am trying to read a csv file using Browse button by the following HTML tag:

```
<input type="file" name="filename" id="filename">
<div id="csvimporthint"></div>
```

and my jquery code to read and process the input file is as below:

```
<script>
$("#filename").change(function(e) {
    var ext = $("input#filename").val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();

    if($.inArray(ext, ["csv"]) == -1) {
    alert('Upload CSV');
    return false;
    }

    if (e.target.files != undefined) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var csvLines;
        var csvValues;
        var i;

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            csvLines = e.target.result.split("\n");
            for(i=1; i<csvLines.length; i++){
                csvValues = csvLines[i].split(",");
                importedLat = csvValues[0];                 
                importedLon = csvValues[1];
                markerFunc(importedLat, importedLon);
                addLayer();
            }
            //$("#csvimporthint").html(importedLat + " " + importedLon);
            reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
        };
    }
    return false;
});  
</script>
```

The problem that I am facing is that my reader.onload is never fired, in result of which I cannot process my file data. Kindly help me find a solution to make this code running.

P.S: To write this above code, I followed this link: http://jsfiddle.net/W8fME/1650/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer of this question myself. The problem was in jquery code in the script tag, correct jquery code is as below:

```
<script>
$("#filename").change(function(e) {
    var ext = $("input#filename").val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();

    if($.inArray(ext, ["csv"]) == -1) {
    alert('Upload CSV');
    return false;
    }

    if (e.target.files != undefined) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var csvLines;
        var csvValues;
        var i;

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            csvLines = e.target.result.split("\n");
            for(i=1; i<csvLines.length; i++){
                csvValues = csvLines[i].split(",");
                importedLat = csvValues[0];                 
                importedLon = csvValues[1];
                markerFunc(importedLat, importedLon);
                addLayer();
            }
        };
        reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
    }
    return false;
});  
</script>
```